# SQL Server 2014 - deprecated datatype problem - Error 596, Cannot continue the execution because the session is in kill state

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, deprecated

I found several columns spread over a dozen SQL Server 2014 databases that are of the deprecated datatypes `text` and `ntext`. So I wanted to alter those to `nvarchar(max)` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <mytable> 
    ALTER COLUMN <mycolumn> NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Exact statement was:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts 
    ALTER COLUMN notes0 NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

I wrote a script doing this in a loop. For about 170 columns this went fine, but the there are 9 columns left producing the error message:

> Error 596, Cannot continue the execution because the session is in kill state
>
> German Version Message:
>   Meldung 596, Ebene 21, Status 1, Zeile 0
>   Die Ausführung kann nicht fortgesetzt werden, weil die Sitzung den KILL-Status aufweist.
>
> Meldung 0, Ebene 20, Status 0, Zeile 0
>   Für den aktuellen Befehl ist ein schwerwiegender Fehler aufgetreten. Löschen Sie eventuelle Ergebnisse.)

Then I tried to add a new column of `nvarchar(max)` to this table and copy the data in it, which produced the same result.

So I made a new table with a similar set of columns, just appropriate data types and copied the data to it => this worked fine!

BUT I couldn't just rename the two tables to put the new table in place of the old, because the indexes wouldn't fit. The application has their names hard coded (yeah I know....)

So I tried to copy the data back from the new table to the new column I added to the old table. Same result.

I still need to change the datatype or move the data to a new column of `nvarchar(max)`. What can I do now?

Thank you in advance, Nils

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      NSc
-- Create date: 180918
-- Description: sucht alle TEXT und NTEXT-Spalten und konvertiert sie in 
NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ConvertAllDeprecatedTEXTColumns2NvarcharMAX]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #DB 
    (
        id INT,
        databaseID INT NOT NULL,
        DatabaseName NVARCHAR(50),
        IsCobra BIT,
        AnzahlAdressen INT
    )

    CREATE TABLE #CobraTables 
    (
        id INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
        DatabaseName NVARCHAR(50),
        CobraTableName NVARCHAR(50),
        CobraTableID INT,
        SQLTableName NVARCHAR(50),
        AnzahlZeilen INT
    )

    CREATE TABLE #CobraColumns 
    (
        id INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
        DatabaseName NVARCHAR(50),
        CobraTableName NVARCHAR(50),
        SQLTableName NVARCHAR (50),
        CobraColumnName NVARCHAR(100),
        SQLColumnName NVARCHAR(50),
        AnzahlZeilen INT,
        ColumnType NVARCHAR(50) 
    )

    CREATE TABLE #SQL 
    (
        id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
        SQLtext NVARCHAR(1000)
    )

    INSERT INTO #DB (id, databaseID, DatabaseName, IsCobra) 
        EXEC CheckIfCobraDB

    DELETE FROM #DB 
    WHERE IsCobra = 0
       OR DatabaseName = 'cobra_main' 
       OR DatabaseName LIKE '%DEV%' 
       OR DatabaseName LIKE '%demo%' 
       OR DatabaseName LIKE '%invent%' 

    -- Tabellennamen ermitteln 
    INSERT INTO #SQL 
        SELECT 
            'INSERT INTO #CobraTables (DatabaseName, CobraTablename, SQLTablename, CobraTableID) SELECT ' + CHAR (39) + databasename + CHAR(39) + ', [Userlevel_Name], [Logical_Name], [ID] FROM [' + databasename + '].dbo.[AP_Tables]' 
        FROM #DB

    DECLARE @i INT
    SET @i = 1

    DECLARE @j INT
    SET @j = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #SQL)

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

    WHILE @i <= @j 
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = (SELECT SQLtext FROM #SQL WHERE id = @i)
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

        SET @i = (@i + 1)
    END

    -- select * from #SQL
    -- select * from #CobraTables

    -- Spalten mit abgekündigten Text-Datentypen finden
    DELETE FROM #SQL

    DBCC CHECKIDENT (#SQL, reseed, 1)

    -- insert into #SQL select 'insert into #CobraColumns (Databasename, cobratablename, sqltablename, cobracolumnname, sqlcolumnname) select distinct' + char (39) + databasename +  char (39) + ', ' + char (39) + cobratablename + char (39) + ', ' + char (39) + SQLTableName + char (39) +  ', userlevel_name, logical_name from [' + databasename + '].dbo.[AP_Fieldinfos] where len([virtual_field_def]) = 0 and logical_name not like (' + CHAR (39) +  '%ID%' + CHAR (39) + ') and [Table_ID] = ' + CAST (CobraTableID as nvarchar (10))  from #CobraTables where SQLTableName not in ('Links', 'linklist', 'images','keywords','keywordlist', 'symbollist') and AnzahlZeilen > 0 order by DatabaseName, CobraTableName
    insert into #SQL select 'use ['+ databasename + ']; insert into #CobraColumns (Databasename, SQLtablename, SQLcolumnname, ColumnType)   select ' + CHAR (39) +  databasename + char (39) + ', o.name, c.name , t.name  from sys.all_columns as c inner join sys.types as t on t.system_type_id=c.system_type_id inner join sys.tables as o on o.object_id=c.object_id where t.name like ' + CHAR (39) + '%text%' + CHAR (39) + ' order by o.name'  from #DB


    --  select * from #SQL   

    SET @i = 1
    SET @j = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #SQL)

    WHILe @i<=@j 
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = (SELECT SQLtext FROM #SQL WHERE id = @i)
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

        SET @i = (@i + 1)
    END

    SELECT * FROM #CobraColumns

    -- delete from  #CobraColumns where SQLTableName= 'Contacts' and SQLColumnName like 'NOTES%' -- and DatabaseName = 'BCM' 

    -- Spalten konvertieren
    DELETE FROM #SQL
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (#SQL, reseed, 1)

    INSERT INTO #SQL 
        SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + DatabaseName + '].dbo.[' + SQLTableName + '] ALTER COLUMN ' + SQLColumnName + ' NVARCHAR(MAX)' 
        FROM #CobraColumns

    SELECT * FROM #SQL

    SET @i = 1
    SET @j = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #SQL)
 -- /***
    WHILE @i <= @j 
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = (SELECT SQLtext FROM #SQL WHERE id = @i)
        PRINT @SQL 

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

        SET @i = (@i + 1)
    END
    -- ***/
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, I found the answer in this post, 
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1809734/CHECKDB--Cannot-continue-the-execution-because-the-session-is-in-the-kill-state

> This error message is caused by your HAG (High Availability Group) SQL
>   Server failing over from one node to the other. If your HAG is in
>   Synchronous-commit mode log entries cannot be committed on the primary
>   node until they have been written to the secondary nodes. If the
>   heartbeat between the machines fails, and the server attempts to fail
>   over it has to ensure that both nodes are in a consistent state. The
>   databases change from being Synchronized to Resolving mode, and any
>   transactions on the primary node that have not been committed to the
>   secondary nodes are rolled back. This rollback is what gives you the
>   error message, as the automatic rollback state is the same as if you
>   had issued a kill command against the SPID.  The cause is usually
>   network related, especially if the nodes are geographically separated,
>   as will be the case with a DR copy at a remote site. If they are not
>   then checking you local NICs and switches. The recommended resolution
>   from Microsoft is to increase the LeaseTimeout and/or
>   HealthChecktimeout values.

First thing I did is increased the disk size, then increased the HealthChecktimeout and it went away.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer. I'll try to enhance the disk space, although i don't have HAGs,because it is a simple singe MS SQL Server without any redundancy.